# File Browsing Dialog for Tables in Spatial Databases

Tags: spatial-database, .net

I am looking for a file browsing object that allows a user to navigate into the different types of geodatabases.  For example, the ability to navigate into a Spatialite/PostGIS/ESRI File Geodatabase...etc database to select a specific spatial table.  I am working on a .NET based app.

In ArcObjects, the equivalent object would be the IGxDialog.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps with SharpMap ? : http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/